# Changing the onclick event delegate of an HTML button?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

How do you change the JavaScript that will execute when a form button is clicked?

I've tried changing its onClicked and its onclicked child attributes like so:

```
$('mybutton').onClick = 'doSomething';
```

and

```
$('mybutton').attributes["onclick"] = 'doSomething()';
```

Neither seem to work. My other options are:

1. To have two buttons and hide one and show the other.
2. To have it directed to a function that evals a string and change the string to the function I want to execute.

Neither seem very elegant.

I'm using Prototype as a js library so it that has any useful tools I can use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Prototype, I believe that it would be something like this:

```
$("mybutton").observe('click', function() {
     // do something here
});
```

EDIT: Or, as it says in [the documentation](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event), you could simply specify the function you want to call on click:

```
$('mybutton').observe('click', respondToClick);

function respondToClick(event) {
    // do something here
}
```

But this is all, again, Prototype-specific.

Comment: This works however it doesn't remove the onclick property that is set in the html... which is bad...

Comment: You are absolutely right. I haven't thought of that when I was answering the question.

Answer (score 3):

If the original onclick event was set through HTML attributes, you can use the following to overwrite it:

```
$("#myButtonId").setAttribute("onclick", "myFunction();");
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the Prototype framework you can do:

```
Event.observe("mybutton", "click", clickHandler);
```

or:

```
Event.observe("mybutton", "click", function() {
  alert("Button clicked!");
});
```

or:

```
$("mybutton").observe("click", clickHandler);
```

or:

```
$("mybutton").observe("click", function() {
  alert("Button clicked!");
});
```

- See the [Event class documentation](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event)

Answer (score 1):

The general way to set an onclick handler in javascript is to set `onclick` to a function, by passing it the name of a function directly, not in a string. So if `myButton` is set to a DOM Element, you would write:

```
myButton.onclick = doSomething;
```

So when you click the 'mybutton' button, the `doSomething` function will be called as `doSomething()`. For anonymous functions, you can write:

```
myButton.onclick = function() {
    alert("myButton was clicked!");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery it's

```
$("#myButtonId").click(myFunction);


function myFunction(){
 alert("Clicked");
}
```

Or if you want to put the function inline:

```
$("#myButtonId").click(function(){
     alert("Clicked");
});
```

If you are using JQuery firstly make sure you use the relevant selector prefix (IE: If your using the Id of the element put a # in front of it). Secondly it's the click method to assign a callback to the click event.

Comment: I'm not using JQuery though. I might next time so this might be useful then.

Answer (score 0):

Last I used Prototype, it was something like this:

```
Event.observe('mybutton', 'click', doSomething);
```

By the way, your examples might've even worked if you didn't quote the function names.

EDIT: Yes, Element.observe(element, eventName, handler) and someElement.observe(eventName, handler) also work. And don't quote the handler name - you want to pass the function not a string!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for your issue with prototype under firefox:

```
$("#myButtonId").writeAttribute('onclick', ''); // first remove the attribute
$("#myButtonId").observe('click', function () { ... }); // then add the event
```